# Controller Spring MVC отображает страницу в браузере как текст в теге <pre>

Tags: spring, mvc, jsp

помогите пожалуйста в решении моей ситуации.
Не могу понят в чем причина, ответа не нашел за 6 часов в интернете.
Запускаю через Eclipse tomcat 9.0

[image: Не интерпретирует в представление, а отображает как текст]

Comment: покажите свой контроллер

Comment: Вы же `.jsp` отправляете?

Answer (score 0):

Настройка моего проекта отображена в скринах:
Если я настрою на работу с html и передам файл того-же формата, работает, а вот с jsp какой-то трабл для меня.

[image: Контроллер]

[image: Конфигурация]

[image: Конфигурация]

Answer (score 0):

Моя проблема заключалась в некомпетентности, использования mavena, а именно d build секции нужно было добавить false
Спасибо за ваше время.